# Using the stack trace from IDE to correct failing app

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I request help making use of the following stack trace. Although this is a Groovy/Grails application, it still boils down to Java. In working along with the book 'Grails in action', I built an application in G/G, Grails v1.3.7. I imported this into the 'Spring Source Tools Suite', which uses Grails v2.2.3. It compiles fine, but won't run. Here is the first part of the stack trace (the entire thing is huge, but most of it just keeps repeating) ...

```
2013-10-17 16:28:16,074 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; 
  nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unsupported connection setting "SHUTDOWN" [90113-164])
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:713)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I latched on to the line that mentions:

```
(Unsupported connection setting "SHUTDOWN" [90113-164])
```

... it appears to be located in: ..\springsource\grails-2.2.3\src\java-addin\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\datasource\DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy in this call:

```
connection.createStatement().executeUpdate('SHUTDOWN')
```

This code comes with the IDE. Try as I might, I can't figure out what I might do to correct this problem. Tomcat problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Grails 1.3.7 is a old version, you should try the latest one. Also, Grails in Action have the second version now :-)

Comment: In future please use the "code" button `{}` to format stack traces (I fixed it for you)

Comment: Thank you Sérgio, I tried to figure out how to format the code - it said to indent four - didn't work - then tried to use the back tick - only worked in setting it apart - sorry. So thanks for formatting it. Now as to the version. Yes I know that it is old. I mentioned that I was importing it into the IDE which uses v2.2.3. As to the problem itself, I nosed around some more and noticed that in DataSource.groovy, the "environments { developement { dataSource { dbCreate { url = " had, after the driver ';shutdown=true'. I removed that and now it works.